# Unable to import pyjmi module when changing directory

Tags: modelica, jmodelica

I am using JModelica 2.1 on Windows, and up until recently I was always able to import pyjmi without any issue. For example, in the IPython console, I would often run the following without issue:

```
cd C:\mydirectory
from pyjmi import *
```

However, recently, I accidentally opened a new IPython console and ran the previous code segment without realizing that I already had one opened which was running an optimization problem. Ever since then, the previous code will throw the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-ecb3494d14c4> in <module>()
----> 1 from pyjmi import *

C:\JModelica.org-2.1\install\Python\pyjmi\symbolic_elimination.py in <module>()
     21 import scipy
     22 import casadi
---> 23 import modelicacasadi_wrapper as ci
     24 import itertools
     25 from collections import OrderedDict

C:\JModelica.org-2.1\install\Python\modelicacasadi_wrapper\__init__.py in <module>()
----> 1 from modelicacasadi_wrapper import *

C:\JModelica.org-2.1\install\Python\modelicacasadi_wrapper\modelicacasadi_wrapper.py in <module>()
    155 SwigPyIterator_swigregister(SwigPyIterator)
    156
--> 157 import casadi.casadi_core
    158 class Printable(_object):
    159     """Proxy of C++ ModelicaCasADi::Printable class."""

ImportError: No module named casadi_core
```

The curious thing is that the above error only happens when I change the current directory. If instead I don't `cd` and stay in the default directory (C:\Users\Public\Documents\JModelica.org), then it imports without any problems and works fine afterwards. It only happens with pyjmi (pyfmi for example will import without issue), which seems to suggest that it might be a problem related to environment variables. However, I can't find any problem with them, in all cases the `JMODELICA_HOME` as well as all other environment variables found with `pyjmi.environ` seem to work fine.

I tried circumventing the issue by installing JModelica 2.2, however the problem still persists (both with 2.1 and 2.2). It should be noted however that I didn't uninstall JModelica 2.1 when doing this.

If anybody has any idea about what is causing this behaviour, I would be very grateful.

**Edit:**
Things have taken a turn for the worst, and now I cannot import pyjmi under any circumstances whatsoever when using JModelica 2.1 (whereas the previous behaviour still holds with JModelica 2.2). I don't know what exactly has changed to cause this.

Comment: Maybe try re-installing [casadi](https://pypi.org/project/casadi/)?

Comment: Do you have casadi_core.py in your install folder? (i.e. in /JModelica.org/install/Python/casadi/)

Comment: @ChristianWinther Yes, in fact pyjmi works perfectly fine (for example I can run the VDP example without issue) in JModelica 2.2, but only if I haven't used the cd command beforehand. In JModelica 2.1, it doesn't work at all under any circumstances. All of this is recent behaviour which I never had prior.

Comment: @matth I'm not using a separate installation of casadi, but rather the one which is installed with JModelica, so I can't reinstall it with pip for example unless I reinstall my entire JModelica installation. I'll try reinstalling, however, seeing as an entirely new installation of JModelica didn't do the trick, I unfortunately doubt it'll do anything. Also, for information, I tried recompiling from sources using the JModelica SDK, but this didn't fix the issue.

Comment: You can do `python -m pip install -U casadi` to make sure the correct pip is used. Just make sure you are using the same python executable. https://docs.python.org/3/installing/#work-with-multiple-versions-of-python-installed-in-parallel

Comment: I've tried reinstalling casadi, but to no avail. I also tried a complete reinstallation of JModelica 2.2 (after uninstalling 2.1), still nothing. One peculiar thing I've noticed since reinstalling 2.2 is that if I launch the IPython console from the start menu (which uses a different default directory, rather than C:/JModelica.org-2.2 as is the case when launching directly with IPython64.bat), then I can't ever import pyjmi, even if I don't cd. I can't make any sense of this behaviour, since the `PYTHONPATH` is the exact same in both cases.

Comment: Just to be 100% sure: Could you try running your code from the console instead of IPython? And to make sure the errors are not due to multiple python executables, please also add the following snippet (as 3 lines of code) to your script: `import sys
print(sys.version)
print(sys.executable)`

Comment: Using the Python console instead of IPython doesn't seem to change the behaviour. The version is 2.7.13, and `sys.executable` returns the same (C:\JModelica.org-2.2\Python27\Python_64\python.exe) in both cases. The contents of `sys.path` are also more or less the same regardless of the current directory (the only difference being the entry for the current directory). However, I did find one difference: when the current directory **isn't** C:\JModelica.org-2.2, `import casadi print(casadi.__file__)` only returns "casadi.pyc", rather than the full `__init__.pyc` path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the problem was that I had a Python script named casadi.py (and casadi.pyc along with it) in a folder in my C:\ drive. This script was completely unrelated to JModelica's casadi module. The order of the paths in `sys.path` made it such that, if the current directory wasn't C:\JModelica.org-2.2, it would find the unrelated casadi.pyc before finding the actual module I wanted. To fix the problem I simply renamed the unrelated script, though I imagine that manually changing the contents of `sys.path` would have done the trick as well.